# Showing that all functions $f(x,y) = g(xy)$ solve a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Lets say we have the following differential equation:

$f''_{uv} = 0$

Where $u=xy$ and $v=y$.

We want to show that all functions on the form $f(x,y) = g(xy)$ (where $g$ is a function of one variable and two times continously deriverable) solve this differential equation.

We get:

$f''_{uv} = 0$

$f'_{v} = h(v)$

$f(u,v) = g(u) + H(v)$

And finally $f(x,y) = g(xy) + H(y)$. According to my material, you can simply just set $H(y) = 0$, and this shows that all functions on the form $f(x,y) = g(xy)$ solve this differential equation. But why can we simply set it equal to $0$?

Comment: You're trying to show that $g(u)$ satisfies your differential equation. You know that all $g(u)+h(v)$ satisfy the differential equation, including for $h\equiv 0$.

Comment: Oh! I guess with a bit of different wording I understand. Thank you!